# Can't return a value from a VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm trying to return a value from my code.  It's much easier to just show the code:

```
Function writeHeaderData() As IXMLDOMNode

    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.LoadXML "<Foo></Foo>"
    Dim Foo As IXMLDOMNode
    Set Foo = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

    'code snip; includes appending lots of things to Foo

    'the error is on this line:
    writeHeaderData = Foo
    Exit Function

End Function
```

I've already Google searched, but it's been of no avail.  This function is being called from the main subroutine, and I'm trying to append the returned IXMLDOMNode to a bigger one, but I keep getting an `"Object variable or With block variable not set`" error on the `writeHeaderData = Foo` line.  What's up here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VB(A), when you want to assign to an **object** variable, *including* assigning the return value of a function, you need to use `Set`, so:

```
'the error is on this line:
writeHeaderData = Foo
```

should be

```
Set writeHeaderData = Foo
```

Comment: Excellent!  This is *highly* unusual, as I'd suspect that if I return a variable that already has a name it would be in scope/initialized.  Thank you, good sir.

Comment: The variable writeHeaderData is in scope and initialised, but its an object and VBA says you always have to use Set to assign to an object: no exceptions allowed.

Comment: You're going to get a Type Mismatch even with the Set statement.  Your function returns a XMLDoc, but Foo is an XMLDOMNode.

Comment: @DickKusleika: Right.  I've fixed that also in the final code.  Thanks!